# Using longtable for figures: the figures overlap with horizontal and vertical lines

Tags: longtable

I have a huge number of plots that I want to insert in longtable to make a figure table, possibly ranging several pages.

However I am not able to scale the figures inside each table cell in such a way that they do not overlap with horizontal and vertical lines in the table. If I simply reduce the width of each table cell, the cell and the figure are reduced the same factor and the figure still overlaps with the lines.

Can anybody help me with a code change that avoiding this overlap?

In addition, how do I place the "figure lacking" text in the middle of their cells, horizontally and vertically?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:** I am not able to correctly format my code lines in this window. I am using Ctr-K and four spaces. How to do this correctly?

[image]

```
\documentclass[9pt,a4paper,twosided]{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{|c|c|c|}
\caption{My caption for figures in longtable}
\label{figtab-1B}\\%
\hline
\multicolumn{3}{c}{The table heading of the first page}\\%
\hline
\endfirsthead
\multicolumn{3}{c}{\tablename\ \thetable\ -- \textit{Continued from last page}}\\%
\hline
\multicolumn{3}{c}{The table heading for the next pages}\\%
\hline
\endhead
\hline \hline
\multicolumn{3}{c}{\tablename\ \thetable\ -- \textit{To be continued on the next page}} \\%
\endfoot
\hline
\endlastfoot
\includegraphics[width=0.33\textwidth]{./figures/1B_-_Alkalitet_til_pH_4_comma_5.jpg}&
figure lacking&
\includegraphics[width=0.33\textwidth]{./figures/1B_-_Ammonium_(NH4-N).jpg}\\%
\hline
\includegraphics[width=0.33\textwidth]{./figures/1B_-_Arsen_(As)_comma_oppsluttet_ICP-MS.jpg}&
\includegraphics[width=0.33\textwidth]{./figures/1B_-_Bly_(Pb)_comma_oppsluttet_ICP-MS.jpg}&
figure lacking\\
\hline
\includegraphics[width=0.33\textwidth]{./figures/1B_-_Kadmium_(Cd)_comma_oppsluttet_ICP-MS.jpg}&
figure lacking&
\includegraphics[width=0.33\textwidth]{./figures/1B_-_Kobber_(Cu)_comma_oppsluttet_ICP-MS.jpg}\\%
\hline
\includegraphics[width=0.33\textwidth]{./figures/1B_-_Krom_(Cr)_comma_oppsluttet_ICP-MS.jpg}&
\includegraphics[width=0.33\textwidth]{./figures/1B_-_Krysen_slash_Trifenylen.jpg}&
\includegraphics[width=0.33\textwidth]{./figures/1B_-_Naftalen.jpg}\\%
\hline
\includegraphics[width=0.33\textwidth]{./figures/1B_-_Nikkel_(Ni)_comma_oppsluttet_ICP-MS.jpg}&
\includegraphics[width=0.33\textwidth]{./figures/1B_-_Pyren.jpg}&
\includegraphics[width=0.33\textwidth]{./figures/1B_-_Sink_(Zn)_comma_oppsluttet_ICP-MS.jpg}\\%
\hline
\includegraphics[width=0.33\textwidth]{./figures/1B_-_Suspendert_stoff.jpg}&
\includegraphics[width=0.33\textwidth]{./figures/1B_-_Total_Fosfor.jpg}&
\includegraphics[width=0.33\textwidth]{./figures/1B_-_Total_Nitrogen.jpg}\\%
\hline
\includegraphics[width=0.33\textwidth]{./figures/1B_- _Total_organisk_karbon_(TOC_slash_NPOC).jpg}&
\includegraphics[width=0.33\textwidth]{./figures/1B_-_Turbiditet.jpg}\\%
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass[9pt,a4paper,twosided]{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[demo,
            export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

%-------------------------------------- only for show page layout
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.25pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
\begingroup
    \expandafter\patchcmd\csname Gin@ii\endcsname   % needed etoolbox
      {\setkeys{Gin}{#1}}%
      {\setkeys{Gin}%
          {width=0.3\linewidth,%                    % standard graphicx settings
           valign=c, margin=0pt 3pt 0pt 3pt,#1}%   % settings from adjustbox
      }
      {}{}
\setlength\tabcolsep{5pt}
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
\begin{longtable}{|c|c|c|}
\caption{My caption for figures in longtable}
\label{figtab-1B}\\%
\hline
\multicolumn{3}{c}{The table heading of the first page}\\%
\hline
\endfirsthead
\multicolumn{3}{c}{\tablename\ \thetable\ -- \textit{Continued from last page}}\\%
\hline
\multicolumn{3}{c}{The table heading for the next pages}\\%
\hline
\endhead
\hline \hline
\multicolumn{3}{c}{\tablename\ \thetable\ -- \textit{To be continued on the next page}} \\%
\endfoot
\hline
\endlastfoot
\includegraphics{./figures/1B_-_Alkalitet_til_pH_4_comma_5.jpg}
    &   figure lacking
        &   \includegraphics{./figures/1B_-_Ammonium_(NH4-N).jpg}                       \\
    \hline
\includegraphics{./figures/1B_-_Arsen_(As)_comma_oppsluttet_ICP-MS.jpg}
    &   \includegraphics{./figures/1B_-_Bly_(Pb)_comma_oppsluttet_ICP-MS.jpg}
        &   figure lacking                                                              \\
\hline
\includegraphics{./figures/1B_-_Kadmium_(Cd)_comma_oppsluttet_ICP-MS.jpg}
    &   figure lacking
        &   \includegraphics{./figures/1B_-_Kobber_(Cu)_comma_oppsluttet_ICP-MS.jpg}    \\
\hline
\includegraphics{./figures/1B_-_Krom_(Cr)_comma_oppsluttet_ICP-MS.jpg}
    &   \includegraphics{./figures/1B_-_Krysen_slash_Trifenylen.jpg}
        &   \includegraphics{./figures/1B_-_Naftalen.jpg}                               \\
\hline
\includegraphics{./figures/1B_-_Nikkel_(Ni)_comma_oppsluttet_ICP-MS.jpg}
    &   \includegraphics{./figures/1B_-_Pyren.jpg}
        &   \includegraphics{./figures/1B_-_Sink_(Zn)_comma_oppsluttet_ICP-MS.jpg}      \\
\hline
\includegraphics{./figures/1B_-_Suspendert_stoff.jpg}
    &   \includegraphics{./figures/1B_-_Total_Fosfor.jpg}
        &   \includegraphics{./figures/1B_-_Total_Nitrogen.jpg}                         \\
\hline
\includegraphics{./figures/1B_- _Total_organisk_karbon_(TOC_slash_NPOC).jpg}
    &   \includegraphics{./figures/1B_-_Turbiditet.jpg}
        &                                                                               \\
\end{longtable}
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. This looks promissing. I tried to put a \begin{center}...\end{center} environment on the outside of the \begingroup...\endgroup environment, but the figure table would not center horizontally on the page. How can I make it center horizontally?

Comment: `longtable` is centered (by default) in text area.`\begingroup`, `\endgroup˙ in my mwe only limited `Gin˙ to `longtable`, in case of use `\begin{center} ... \end{center}` can be omitted. to my answer i will add lines which show page layout.

Comment: Thanks a lot! You saved my life just now :)

Answer (score 0):

Add this  to your preamble:

```
\usepackage{cellspace}
\setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{3pt}
\setlength{\cellspacebottomlimit}{3pt}
```

and the first line of the longtable code with

```
\begin{longtable}{|Sc|Sc|Sc|}
```

(if you load `siunitx` replace `Sc` with `Cc`).

Comment: Thanks! but my MikTex does not find the cellspace.sty file for some reason

Comment: Did you install it?  It's not installed by default (do that with MiKTeX Package Manager).

Comment: Yes I installed it, by using your code.

Comment: And the code removes the overlapping?

Comment: No, I still get this error message about not finding the cellspace.sty.

Comment: How did you install it?

Comment: Miktex auto installs it, I presume..?

Comment: Check with MiKTeX Package Manager whether it is installed. Just in case, refresh the filename database.